# Parse a list of JSONs with Gson

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I'm trying to parse a JSON file with Gson but I'm having a lot of problems trying to get all values. The structure of the JSON can be seen in the next image:

[image]

As you can see, it is a list of tweets' jsons (not an array, without brackets) that I need to write in a file (one per line). The thing is, how can I parse this JSON and get each tweet separately?

Comment: This should help a little http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: [org.json](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java) library help you.

Comment: @Pshemo That is a really cool tool, but I just need to get each tweet and an String.

Comment: You still didn't explain what is stopping you. Do you know basics about how to use Gson? Did you create code which doesn't work as you intended (if yes post your code and explain what problem you are having with it)?

Comment: I know some basics and I understand the code generated by your tool, but I don't see how to get a whole object as an string and not as an object with each value.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will get you close. The JsonTestFiles.getJson("tweets.json") just returns the json as a string, which is what you're starting with.

```
@Test    
public void testGson() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Tweets tweets = gson.fromJson(JsonTestFiles.getJson("tweets.json"), Tweets.class);
         System.out.println(tweets);

    }
private static class Tweets {
    public Map<String, Data> id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tweets{" +
                "id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}

private static class Data {
    public String created_at;
    public int id;
    public String id_str;
    public String text;
    public String source;
    public boolean truncated;
    public String in_reply_to_status_id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" +
                "created_at='" + created_at + '\'' +
                ", id=" + id +
                ", id_str='" + id_str + '\'' +
                ", text='" + text + '\'' +
                ", source='" + source + '\'' +
                ", truncated=" + truncated +
                ", in_reply_to_status_id='" + in_reply_to_status_id + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and the json:

```
{
  "id": {
    "50413592" : {
    "created_at" : "Sunday",
    "id" : 50413592,
    "id_str" : "50413592",
    "text" : "Hello text",
    "source":"the source",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": ""
  },
  "50413593" : {
    "created_at" : "Sunday",
    "id" : 50413593,
    "id_str" : "50413593",
    "text" : "Hello text",
    "source":"the source",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": ""
  },
  "50413594" : {
    "created_at" : "Sunday",
    "id" : 50413594,
    "id_str" : "50413594",
    "text" : "Hello text",
    "source":"the source",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(line).getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject o = jsonObject.get("id").getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray tweets = parser.parse("[" + o.toString() + "]").getAsJsonArray();

for (JsonElement element : tweets) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : element.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
        String tweet = entry.getValue().toString();
    }
}
```

This way I don't need a new class. Not sure if it is the best solution but it works.